# PowerShell Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

I am running into the following error when running this script:

Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."

```
#Variables to configure
$MailServer = "domain.com"
$ReportSender = "email@domain.com"
$ReportRecipient = "email@domain.com"
$MailSubject = ("yourdomain.local exchange2010 Mailbox Report for " + $MailServer + " - " + ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd'))

#SendEmailFunction
Function send-mailmessage
{ param($smtphost,$htmlFileName)
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $ReportSender, $ReportRecipient, $MailSubject, (Get-Content $htmlFileName)
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true
$smtp.send($msg)
}

$exdata = Get-MailboxStatistics -Server $MailServer | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -descending | Select-Object DisplayName, ItemCount, TotalItemSize, Database, StorageLimitStatus

$fileName = "exchange2010Report.html"
New-Item -ItemType file $fileName -Force

# HTML start
Add-Content $fileName "<html>"

# HEAD start
Add-Content $fileName "<head>"

add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
add-content $fileName  "<!--"
add-content $fileName  "td {"
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;"
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "body {"
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
add-content $fileName  ""
add-content $fileName  "table {"
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "-->"
add-content $fileName  "</style>"

# HEAD end
Add-Content $fileName "</head>"

# HEAD start
Add-Content $fileName "<body>"

# TABLE start
Add-Content $fileName "<table width='100%'>"

# TABLE Header
Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor='#7C7C7C'>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='35%'>DisplayName</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%'>ItemCount</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%'>TotalItemSize</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='25%'>Database</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='20%'>StorageLimitStatus</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"

$alternateTableRowBackground = 0

# TABLE Content
while($alternateTableRowBackground -le $exdata.length)
{
if(($alternateTableRowBackground % 2) -eq 0)
{
Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
}
else
{
Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor='#FCFCFC'>"
}
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='30%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].DisplayName + "</td>") 
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='10%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].ItemCount + "</td>")
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='15%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].TotalItemSize + "</td>")
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='25%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].Database + "</td>")
#BelowLimit or NoChecking
if(($exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus -eq "BelowLimit") -or ($exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus -eq "NoChecking"))
{
Add-Content $fileName ("<td bgcolor='#007F00' width='20%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus + "</td>")
}
#IssueWarning
if($exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus -eq "IssueWarning")
{
Add-Content $fileName ("<td bgcolor='#7F7F00' width='20%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus + "</td>")
}
#ProhibitSend or MailboxDisabled
if(($exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus -eq "ProhibitSend") -or ($exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus -eq "MailboxDisabled"))
{
Add-Content $fileName ("<td bgcolor='#7F0000' width='20%'>" + $exdata[$alternateTableRowBackground].StorageLimitStatus + "</td>")
}
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"

$alternateTableRowBackground = $alternateTableRowBackground + 1
}
# Summe Mailboxsize
Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor='#7C7C7C'>"
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='30%'></td>") 
$tempdata = MailboxStatistics -Server $MailServer | %{$_.ItemCount} | Measure-Object -Sum
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='10%'>" + ($tempdata | Select-Object -expand Sum) + "</td>")
$tempdata = MailboxStatistics -Server $MailServer | %{$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()} | Measure-Object -Sum
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='15%'>" + ($tempdata | Select-Object -expand Sum) + " MB</td>")
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='25%'></td>")
Add-Content $fileName ("<td width='20%'></td>")


#TABLE end
Add-Content $fileName "</table>"

# HEAD end
Add-Content $fileName "</body>"

# HTML end
Add-Content $fileName "</html>"

send-mailmessage $MailServer $fileName
```

The report is generated fine and the file gets generated but it will not an email out and I get the error. Not sure exactly why I am getting it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually indicates an issue with sending the email through the specified SMTP host (ie. the message was rejected, connection closed, host not found etc.). Are you sure that `domain.com` is the correct smtp server fqdn and that you're allowed to send mails through it anonymously?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the actual domain I am using is the correct one as I use this for many other PS scripts and it works fine.

Comment: From the same host? Using the same Recipient and Sender addresses? There any many ways to pose restrictions on smtp clients on a mail gateway

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, Yes, Yes. We run Exchange 2010 and it has anonymous send granted as we run multiple web servers and send 1000's of emails a day through the gateway with no authentication (internally). I don't think that's the issue. I have 100's of PS scripts I use often and they all use the same format and all work. This one does not.

Comment: A good way to validate that this is a script-centric problem, IMHO, would be to run this script on a machine that also has no issues with the same outgoing mail server.  My guess is, you're on a different server/system, when you run this failing script - is that accurate?

Comment: @gravity - that's correct. The only difference with this script is I am running it on the Exchange server using EMS rather than running it from a different box connecting to Exchange. I agree with your approach to a certain degree I just don't understand why that would have any impact on the send-mailmessage command.

Comment: @gravity - I have tested your theory and tried running the script from a different box but got the same error. :(

Comment: Is the account that you are using to execute the script the same as other functional scripts that send mail?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Yes, I am using an enterprise domain admin account in all cases.

Comment: what version of powershell you have

Comment: @Owl 2.0 - this is running on Exchange 2010. I have also run from a server running 3.0 with the same error.

Comment: can you telnet telnet to port 587 on smtp?

Comment: @Owl I am running the command within the EMS (Exchange Management Console) on the Exchange server itself. Are you asking I telnet to itself?

Comment: try a test
`Send-MailMessage -To "someone@domain.com" -From "test@domain.com" -SmtpServer 10.1.0.3 -Subject "test" -Body "this is test"`

Comment: @Owl - test email received!

Answer (score 1):

The email server requires authentication, so I added this line before the send

```
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@yourdomain.dom", "password")
```

Answer (score 0):

have this

```
$emailSmtpServer = "mail.somewhere.com"
$emailFrom = "someone@somewhere.com"
$emailTo = "someone@somewhere.com"
$emailSubject = "$domain report $env:computername subject $date"
$emailBody = "Get-Content c:\exchange2010Report.html"
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody -BodyAsHTML -SmtpServer  $emailSmtpServer
```